# RGB to HSL Hue rotate effect with pure JS

Tags: javascript, rgb

How can I make this exactly similar effect with pure css/javascript only?

I have the input value HUEROTATE between -100 to 100 that this code uses,
 I now need to display on web page the PNG file with a same color that code below outputs.

```
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Adjust HSB effect

varying mediump vec2 vTex;
uniform lowp sampler2D samplerFront;
precision mediump float;
uniform float huerotate;
uniform float satadjust;
uniform float briadjust;

vec3 rgb_to_hsl(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
    vec4 p = mix(vec4(c.bg, K.wz), vec4(c.gb, K.xy), step(c.b, c.g));
    vec4 q = mix(vec4(p.xyw, c.r), vec4(c.r, p.yzx), step(p.x, c.r));

    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
    float e = 1.0e-10;
    return vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);
}

vec3 hsl_to_rgb(vec3 c)
{   
    vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
    vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
    return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
}

void main(void)
{
    // Retrieve front and back pixels
    vec4 front = texture2D(samplerFront, vTex);
    vec3 rgb = rgb_to_hsl(front.rgb) + vec3(huerotate, 0, (briadjust - 1.0) * front.a);
    rgb.y *= satadjust;
    rgb = hsl_to_rgb(rgb);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, front.a);
}
```

Comment: Color Conversion routines in JS are e.g. here: https://gist.github.com/mjackson/5311256 ... apart from that: What exactly is your question? Are you trying to hue-rotate a PNG image on a web page? If yes: load the PNG into a canvas (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images), then for each pixel of the canvas: convert pixel to HSL or HSV, rotate hue, convert back to RGB, put pixel back on the canvas.

Comment: Thanks, I need to get the exactly same colors/output on screen for the png file on html page with JS  that code block above does. I want to make a slider that can be used to adjust the colors like the code block does.